# Scanning non-txt files with unspecified filename

Tags: java

I want to make a tool that does the 2 following things::

- Open files that are not .txt but can be opened as .txt and return them as a string. It just returns an empty string at the moment.
- The filenames are unknown, just the file extension at the end and the the YYYYMMDD number in front are always the same, therefore I'd like the app to simply scan every file in the same folder (not the same file twice, obviously). How can this be done?

That's what I've got so far. Java Code:

```
public String readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    File file = new File(filename);
    String output = "";
    try{
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error: File " + filename + " not found!");
    }
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        output=output+scanner.nextLine();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: How do you call the method? The parameter `filename` should be the whole path, not only the name. The code works fine for me as it is!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to call your readFile(file) method for every file in your directory.

You can use the File.listFiles() method to get the list of files in a directory:

```
File f = new File("your/directory");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

Then you can loop through the files (continuing previous example):

```
for (File file : files) {
  System.out.println(readFile(file.toString()));
}
```

By the way, you should use a StringBuilder to append the strings so you won't have to make a new object every time a new line is read.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define method that accept `dir`, `matcher` - will be called on each file to check if file name corret or not, `consumer` - will be called on each mathed file
public static void readFiles(Path dir, BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher, Consumer<Path> consumer) throws IOException {
    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> localMatcher = (path, attr) -> attr.isRegularFile();
    localMatcher = matcher != null ? localMatcher.and(matcher) : localMatcher;
    Files.find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, localMatcher).forEach(consumer);
}
```

**Client code:**

```
// define matcher to check if given file name match pattern or not
BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher = (path, attr) -> {
    String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
    int dot = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    String ext = dot >= 0 ? fileName.substring(dot + 1) : null;
    String name = dot >= 0 ? fileName.substring(0, dot) : fileName;
    // check 'name' and 'ext' match the required pattern
    return true;
};

// define consumer to accept file path and read it line by line
Consumer<Path> consumer = path -> {
    try {
        String content = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        System.out.println("file name: " + path);
        System.out.println(content);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

readFiles(Paths.get("H://one"), matcher, consumer);
```